# Fade in effect on one of the images on the page.

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image on my webpage. The image is not the background but it covers almost 30% of the page. and the image is huge in size for a webpage(200KB). So when the image completes loading it just flashes on the page which looks very ugly. So I wanted the image to fade-in after its downloaded completely on the webpage. As the background color of the image and the background color of the web-page are the same it will look like a good animation. As if only the contents of the image are fading in. Any ways is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

since you are using such a large image I'm going to assume that it is a JPG. And assuming you are not on a mobile device and it is flashing in, I am also going to assume that it is a baseline JPG. Wow, that's a lot of assumptions :)

I would recommend using a progressive JPG, it will load around the same time as a content it a rough form. It will progressively enhance it self in layers until it reaches full quality.

You can also wrap it in a div of the same dimensions to keep your content from jerking around.

If you want it to fade in you can add display:none; to you image and using jquery on document ready use the fadeIn method.

```
img {
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    display:none;
}​

<img id="myimg" src="http://placehold.it/400x400" >​

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myimg').fadeIn('fast');
});​
```